# Bootstrap carrousel works fine in my computer, but not on the web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my computer the arrow links and the carrousel work just fine in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera and Chrome.  But in the site not the carrousel, nor the arrows links work.  I have tried everything I could find about the code. But couldnt find why,  I have even suspected the hosting service provider.  But I don't think so.  Anyway here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ense&ntilde;ame a vivir en libertad centro de rehabilitacion</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400'        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/moveme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
<img class="img-responsive" src='images/NewLogo_name_300px.png'  alt=''/>
</div> 
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#medico">Medico</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Testimonios</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery_cert.html">Certificaciones</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>    
</nav>
</div>
<!-- End Navigation -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg">
        <div class="container active">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Recuperaci&oacute;n</h1>
                <p align="center">El primer paso es estar alejado de las fuentes que propician la adicci&oacute;n, para dar paso a la deshabituaci&oacute;n.</p>
                <p><a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Contacto</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg">
        <div class="container active">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Servicio</h1>
                <p align="center">El segundo paso consiste en crear nuevos h&aacute;bitos, mejorando los propios juicios y actitudes en pro de una vida m&aacute;s sana.</p>
                <p><a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Contacto</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg">
        <div class="container active">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Libertad</h1>
                <p align="center">El tercer paso consiste en adquirir las herramientas para vivir libre de adicciones a trav&eacute;s de la pr&aacute;ctica de principios espirituales y sociales que nos llevan a un sentido interno de libertad.</p>
                <p><a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Contacto</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>    

<!--Carousel End -->
<div class="intro-block" id="info" >
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img class="img-responsive tpad" src="images/logo2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <h1>LA MEJOR OPCION<span class="text-muted">&raquo; Desde el a&ntilde;o 2006</span></h1>
            <p class="lead justify">Somos el centro de rehabilitaci&oacute;n con mayor arraigo en Campeche, los que colaboramos como consultores y asesores en adicci&oacute;n sumamos m&aacute;s de 70 a&ntilde;os de experiencia trabajando en pro de la SOBRIEDAD y la vida en libertad sin el consumo de substancias.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
</div>
<!-- End Intro Text -->


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can explain me why it works in my computer and not in any browser if I go to the site, btw, it is www.vivirlibertad.com and it is in Spanish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the errors? `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` and `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Meaning jQuery is not loaded (yet).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a jQuery conflict on the site. I checked the console and it's saying "$ is not defined".

I see you've the following code just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    })
</script>
```

This is causing the conflict with your other JS files. Change the above to:

```
<script>
    var $car = jQuery.noConflict();
    $car('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    })
</script>
```

Check the official documentation on jQuery conflicts here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I did put that code, still doesn't work.  It is a very strange thing.  I will keep looking how to solve this.  First time this happens.  However, I don't understand why the page works fine in all browsers if read from my computer, but not from the site... ??? AW, thanks again.

Comment: I found the answer, changed jQuery version from 1.10.2 to 2.1.0  that solved it.  I left the code you provided.  So many thanks.